# Typeof Buffer data returns type is object

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, buffer

Tried following code:

```
console.log(typeof bufferData);
```

Where bufferData holds:

```
<Buffer 4a 95 26 e9 93 bf eb 1a bf 2d 94 0b ad c7 08 15 ca c5 79 14 ac 67 d3 79 f1 9a 00 90 34 32 a7 16>
```

This is buffer data, But typeof the bufferData returns object.

Input:

```
console.log(typeof bufferData);
```

Expected results is

```
buffer
```

Comment: A buffer is a type of object, so it returns `object`

Comment: But if any function requires buffered data only, What should I use to make data buffer.